# Get unread email count using PHP

Tags: php, email, count, imap

**My need:**
I want to get the count of unread email in my GMail account (or any other email service), and after I get that I need it to be displayed in a webpage on my local PHP server. So I need a scripting language, that would be PHP. But I tried many examples but none of them seems to work. So basically what I want is **a PHP script that can access my GMail account and return the count of unread emails to a webpage**.

I have tried this script in vain, it always keeps showing "Error" on my webpage.

```
<?php

function CountUnreadMail($host, $login, $passwd) {
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $count = 0;
    if (!$mbox) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $headers = imap_headers($mbox);
        foreach ($headers as $mail) {
            $flags = substr($mail, 0, 4);
            $isunr = (strpos($flags, "U") !== false);
            if ($isunr)
            $count++;
        }
    }

    imap_close($mbox);
    return $count;
}

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$count = CountUnreadMail($hostname, $username, $password);

?>
```

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359855/chris) helped, I tries this script but the only thing that I see is a blank page. Here is another script that I tried in vain:

```
<?php

function mailCount($host, $login, $passwd) {
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $mail = '';

    if($mail = imap_check($mbox)) {
        return $mail->Nmsgs;
    }
}

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'phpimap123'; //GMail username
$password = 'phptesting'; //Password

$count = mailCount($hostname, $username, $password);

echo $count;

?
```

PS: I have made a GMail account for **testing purposes only**.

I am running Mac OS X Lion on a MacBook Air. with PHP enabled and running, and I also have MAMP and it is also running.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it through IMAP why don't you just use:

```
function mailCount($host, $login, $passwd)
{
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $mail = '';

    if($mail = imap_check($mbox))
    {
        return $mail->Nmsgs;
    }
}

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$count = mailCount($hostname, $username, $password);
```

This will give you the unread mail count.

Comment: Where will I put my account details (password and username)

Comment: This would be done just as you have now.  I added the $mbox variable in there just as you have it.  Go ahead and just throw in your $mbox connection code above the if() statement.  Feel free to also add in the login credentials into the function as well if you'd like.  I prefer to build these sorts of things into classes and send all that data into a constructor, but whatever you are comfortable with is fine :)

Comment: Well can u please paste the final code here. I'm really new to PHP.

Comment: $mail=''    - what do i have to add here, the mail host ({imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX) or my username, or leave it blank

Comment: You don't need to add anything.  $mail = ''; is just initiating a variable as to set off PHP's Notice error.  Set your $username and $password and you're good to go.

Comment: i tried to display it to a webpage using echo $count; but it returns none, just blank

Comment: Are there messages in the inbox?  I just ran it on my account and it returned a valid count.  Do you have IMAP enabled on your GMail Account?

Comment: yes i have enabled imap, and i have unread emails in my account, btw u ran it on a php server, right? and is the no. of unread messages a matter, bcoz i have over 2000 mails

Comment: can u test with this account, phpimap123@gmail.com, pass= phptesting

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to test out your code, although yes I run this script on my server.  I build a full IMAP PHP Client that is basically a copy of GMail for businesses and this exact code is used on that server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password,OP_READONLY) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$unread = count (imap_search($inbox, 'UnSeen'));
```

---

*imap_check* will give you: *Date, Driver, Mailbox, Nmsgs, Recent*
(*Nmsgs* = total messages, *Recent* = this is NOT unread count but recent)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `if (!$mbox)` with `if ($mbox === FALSE)`

You should be doing a specific type check, it is bad practice to test a handle in that manner.

Also, try logging into your account via [gmail.com](http://gmail.com). It is possible you have too many invalid attempts and Gmail wants you to enter a captcha first, which cannot be done via IMAP.